# Protractor Counting Table Row in async method

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

I am trying to count the rows of a table using Protractor. Below is my code

```
this.rowNumbersInFileMatches = async function () {
    expect(await locator.Student_List_Table.isPresent()).toBeTruthy();

   // This is test using conventional .then function

    $$('#studentListTable > tbody > tr').then(function(Rows){

        R1 = Rows.length;
        console.log('Number of Rows in Then Method' + R1);

    });

    //This is using async await

    let R2 = $$('#studentListTable > tbody > tr');
    console.log('\n*** Number of Rows in the table is : ' + await R2.length);

};
```

When the script is executing the .then block, it correctly identifies the rows and returns the numbers of rows, but when using the async await function, it is returning undefined.

Below is the related log:

```
Started
..Total number of records to be shown: 2
.
*** Number of Rows in the table is : undefined
Number of Rows in Then Method2
```

How can I fix this in the async await method? I am trying to avoid the .then function altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$$` which is alias for `element.all` returns an [ElementArrayFinder](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder) object, which has [count](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.count) method. Hence your code can be rewrited like so

```
const items = $$('#studentListTable > tbody > tr');
const countOfItems = await items.count();
```